# fail to initialize dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I got a code with a list which im trying to change to dictionary (its a must , so i cant use list). my problem its that in 'BankRates.cs'  i fail to add objects to my dictionary. i know add should get a string as well in order for the program to work properly but i just cant figure out whats the key i should insert in the 'Add' method.

i have this 4 cs files:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Converter
{
    class Currency
    {
        //members

        //getters and setters
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Rate { get; set; }
        public double Unit { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }

        //constractor
        public Currency(string code, string name, double rate, double unit, string country)
        {
            this.Code = code;
            this.Name = name;
            this.Rate = rate;
            this.Unit = unit;
            this.Country = country;
        }

        //override ToString method for visualization    
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return  (Name + "-" +Code);
        }
    }
}
```

currencyDictionary:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Converter
{
    class CurrencyDic
    {
        //setter and getter
        public Dictionary<string,Currency> currencyDic { get; set; }
        //constractor
        public CurrencyDic()
        {
            currencyDic = new Dictionary<string,Currency>();
        }
        public CurrencyDic(Dictionary<string,Currency> cur)
        {
            currencyDic = new Dictionary<string,Currency>(cur);
        }
        // implements foreach
        public IEnumerator<Currency> GetEnumerator()
        {
            foreach (Currency cur in currencyDic.Values) { yield return cur;}
        }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Converter
{
    interface IBankRates
    {
         void GetRates();
         double Convert(Currency from, Currency to, double amount);
    }
}
```

and the last one:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;



namespace Converter
{
    class BankRates:IBankRates
    {
        private string Bank_URL = "http://www.boi.org.il/currency.xml";
        CurrencyDic currencyDic = new CurrencyDic();
        public void GetRates()
        {
            XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
            try
            {
               xdoc = XDocument.Load(Bank_URL);}
               catch (XmlException)
            {
               MessageBox.Show("Failed to load Xml file");
               System.Environment.Exit(1);

            }
                //load the xml
                var allCurencies = from currency in xdoc.Descendants("CURRENCY")        //linq query
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       Name = currency.Descendants("NAME").First().Value,
                                       Unit = currency.Descendants("UNIT").First().Value,
                                       Code = currency.Descendants("CURRENCYCODE").First().Value,
                                       Cuntry = currency.Descendants("COUNTRY").First().Value,
                                       Rate = currency.Descendants("RATE").First().Value
                                   };


                foreach (var currency in allCurencies)                                  //create the currency list
                {
                    currencyDic.Add(****What Goes Here?****,new Currency(currency.Code, currency.Name, double.Parse(currency.Rate), double.Parse(currency.Unit), currency.Cuntry));
                   // Console.WriteLine(currency.Code + currency.Cuntry + currency.Name, currency.Rate + currency.Unit);
                }


        }
        //returns the list
        public CurrencyDic getDic()
        {
            return currencyDic;
        }

        //makes the converting calculation
        public double Convert(Currency from,Currency to, double amount)
        {
            double inRate, outRate, excangeRate;
            inRate = from.Rate / from.Unit;
            outRate = to.Rate / to.Unit;
            excangeRate = inRate / outRate;
            return (amount * excangeRate);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: TL;DR; condense your code down to the relevant parts

Comment: Don't post the whole project. Post only relevant code.

Comment: Also: your class `CurrencyDic` does not even have a `Add` method

Comment: You're creating a dictionary from `string` to `Dictionary`; the "What Goes Here?" would be: the string that you intend to use as the key... quite possibly `currency.Code`, but only you know for sure

Comment: Are you asking what to use as the key? It's a string. And as @derape says, you're not exposing an `Add` method on your wrapper class.

Comment: Btw; why does the `CurrencyDic` class even exist? That seems entirely unnecessary (and poorly implemented)

Comment: Why would you want to change code which can perfectly use a `List` to using a `Dictionary`?

Comment: because that's what the assignment is all about...

Answer (score 0):

it seems you have another dictionary in currencyDic.

this.currencyDic.currencyDic.Add("string", "some object Currency");

Comment: the currencyDic itself is a Dictionary<string, Currency>()

Comment: He got a class `CurrencyDic` he created which just inherits from object and that class contains a field `currencyDic` which is a `Dictionary<string, Currency>`.